# Are there any ball tracking algorithms/patterns around in game programming

Tags: tracking

I have set of players, and a ball, the players can kick the ball around the ground (not yet a football game, neither a Foosball game too ). Are there any algorithms/ patterns for addressing the problems with tracking the ball and taking decisions, Is that too much to ask.What I was looking at is something like a collision detection algorithm for the common problem of 2 objects interacting with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [phys2d](http://www.cokeandcode.com/phys2d/) if you are using Java

Or [box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) for C++

Comment: This library is interesting, Thanks.